Anchor - Stuck with error SendTransactionError
I have been trying to write some custom contract in solana using Rust but always ending up with below error:
Catch the SendTransactionError and call getLogs() on it for full details.
at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/home/user1/smart_client/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:8152:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/home/user1/smart_client/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:8117:20)
at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/home/user1/smart_client/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/provider.js:200:23)
at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/home/user1/smart_client/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/provider.js:89:20)
at async MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/home/user1/smart_client/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/rpc.js:15:24) {
signature: '',
transactionMessage: 'invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly',
transactionLogs: undefined
attached one image to this

The error says "failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly" which means that the transaction message isn't being created properly. Are you adding instructions to an existing message? That's usually the cause of the issue
